# How to subscribe to PKPassLibraryNotificationName

Tags: ios, swift, notificationcenter

I need to observe the .PKPassLibraryDidChange and .PKPassLibraryRemotePaymentPassesDidChange notifications that are specified in https://developer.apple.com/documentation/passkit/pkpasslibrarynotificationname

However they are not a subclass of NSNotification.Name so the

```
let observer = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: PKPassLibraryNotificationName.PKPassLibraryDidChange, object: nil, queue: nil) { notification in  
     ...  
}
```

doesn't compile.

Is there any additional import needed to be able to observe `PKPassLibraryNotificationName` on the NotificationCenter?

Comment: I don't think PKPassLibrary actually posts any notifications. You can omit the name and specify an instance of the library, or even omit the object too and check all notifications. Nothing is ever posted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your actual question, Notification.Name is just a string.  You can create the notification name like this:

```
    let notification = NSNotification.Name(rawValue: PKPassLibraryNotificationName.PKPassLibraryDidChange.rawValue)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: notification, object: myPassLibrary, queue: nil) { (notification) in
        // do something here
    }
```

This compiles, but I've never seen it do anything useful. PKPassLibrary just never seems to post notifications.

Comment: This code is correct for your local wallet (e.g. Apple Pay wallet on the phone running this code). There's also PKPassLibraryRemotePaymentPassesDidChange for paired remote wallets, e.g. Apple Watch.

For me, these notifications get posted every time I add or remove a card from my local or remote wallets, as expected. Perhaps you have a config issue around getting Apple's permission for your app's bundle ID, or the `com.apple.developer.payment-pass-provisioning` entitlement, or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that notifications works fine.

According to Apple:

> PassKit posts this notification on an arbitary queue, and only does so if an instance of PKPassLibrary exists

So you need to init PKPassLibrary() and save to some property and you will start receiving notifications.